# Where can a virtual function be defined?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I have a question about virtual functions in C++, for example, `A` is a base class, and class `B` inherits `A`, and class `C` inherits `B`, can we define a virtual function in `B`, and redefine it in `C`? What I mean is, should this virtual function be defined in class `A`, because `A` is the base class (i.e the root of `B` and `C`) for all the `B` and `C`?

Comment: `virtual` applies to sub-classes not super-classes.

Comment: "redefine"? You mean overload or override?

Comment: I mean the implementation of virtual function in B and C is different

Comment: @ratzily Then that's overriding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not it does not have to be ... B is a specialized object from A and it is high likely B has more features than A has. And if C is derived, it is very normal to have a function overridden from B which is not defined in A.

Example

- Let's assume A is a Form
- Let's assume B is a Circle ... a circle has a GetDiameter function, which a form does not have.
- Let's assume C is an Ellipse, although an ellipse has not a real diameter, the GetDiameter function is overridden to get the diameter of the 'smallest' of the two diameters.

Answer (score 3):

`virtual` can be used anywhere in a class hierarchy, but that virtual function can only be overridden in the sub-classes (i.e. it does not apply to the super classes).

```
struct A {
  void funcA();
};

struct B : A {
  virtual funcB();
};

struct C : B {
  virtual funcB();
};

//....
  B* b = new C();
  b->funcB(); // calls C's implementation
  A* a = new C();
  a->funcB(); // fails to compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not problem at all - try it:

```
class A
{

}

class B : public A
{
public: 
 virtual void myFunc(): { std::cout << "B here!"; }
}

class C : public B
{
public: 
 virtual void myFunc(): { std::cout << "No, C here!"; }
}
```